# Google official Place Autocomplete Address Form example error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I am new in this field, and trying to implement Autocomplete Address Form on one APP. But the example code has some error if I try to run it. The error below is shown in my console. Do you know why?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

I have replace the js link with my api link.
Here is my implement demo:
https://plnkr.co/edit/1ptaVzmD7EwPZ6dU23gR?p=preview

```
try.html:161 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setBounds' of undefined
    at file:///Users/shen/Desktop/new%20meetup/try.html:161:25(anonymous function) @ try.html:161
try.html:161 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setBounds' of undefined
    at file:///Users/shen/Desktop/new%20meetup/try.html:161:25(anonymous function) @ try.html:161
js?key=AIzaSyBDhab7yuMx-2lllD8kwZIF-yIVGnsCx-0&libraries=places:34 

Google Maps API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#api-not-activated-map-error
```

You can try it on your browser.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the Places API Web Service in your project in order to use the places library of Maps JavaScript API.

The error message seems to be clear: "Google Maps API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError"

Look at this blog post where Google announced this change on June 22, 2016:

https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html

> We now count Google Maps JavaScript API client-side requests towards the daily limit of the associated web service API.*